# How to pass NSInputStream or NSOutputStream in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to pass a stream from one function to another so that it can read from it in that function.

```
var instream = NSInputStream()
foo(instream)
```

where foo is just:

```
func foo (instream: NSInputStream) {
    instream.read(...);
}
```

Is that the right way to do it? Seems like I should be passing it by reference like

```
foo(&instream)

func foo (instream: UnsafeMutablePointer<NSInputStream>) {
    // how to dereference a stream pointer in Swift?
}
```

but the compiler is saying cannot invoke 'foo' with an argument list of type '(inout NSInputStream)'

Comment: NSInputStream is a *class* and therefore a *reference type*, so your first method is just fine.